# parse_mode in sendMessage method in telegram bots api- php

Tags: php, api, bots, telegram

I send it to core of telegram but my bot do not send me the message with `parse_mode=>'HTML'`:

```
$parameters = array('chat_id' => $chat_id, parse_mode => 'HTML');
$url = '<br><br><a href="https://t.me/' . $us['result']['username'] . '/">anchor text</a>';
$response .= $url;
$parameters += array('text' => $response);
```

but it work without `parse_mode=>'HTML'`

Answer (score 2):

telegram do not support `<br>` tag in html elements!
it will working with delete that! I used `enter` instnce of `<br>`!

Comment: or use `\n\r` (php)